# Home Electrical Questions & Network PDUs

Tags: electrical

I'm in the middle of a home network upgrade and likely need to also do some electrical upgrades as well.

I have a set of pictures of all the equipment [here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/nathanfarrar/albums/72157672721854684/with/30813013191/).

- I have a [GE TLM2020 200AMP](https://flic.kr/p/NWQKj8) main panel.
- I have a [GE TLM812SCUD MOD2](https://flic.kr/p/NUo3Ho) subpanel.

  - I believe this is rated for 125A, but I'm not 100% sure.
  - I had a licensed electrician install it a few years ago.
  - There are only two circuits in the subpanel (they appear to be 20A each), one for a treadmill in the basement and one for the current network equipment.

*First questions, regarding the breaker in the subpanel:

- The breaker looks like it's either two "slim" breakers in a single slot or one breaker with two switches on it. Either way it's definitely connected to two circuits.
- I looked it up and it appears there are "slimline" breakers and "1-pole" or "2-pole" breakers. 2-pole breakers are for powering a 240V circuit, which is not what I want, so I assume this is 2x "slimline" 1-pole breakers occupying a single slot.
- It has the # "AP120" on it. When I google "GE AP120 Slimline" I get [this](http://a.co/8jkYouv), which leads mt to believe it's two of those installed in a single slot.

Back to the network & PDU:

- My current equipment is connected to a [DLI 16-Outlet/8 Circuit PDU](https://amzn.com/B01019IMLS).

  - The PDU is has two input circuits, each designed to be hooked up to a separate 15A circuit.
  - The input connectors are standard NEMA 5-15.
  - The PDU has an onboard 15A fuse for each input circuit.
  - The PDU has 8 'output' circuits (two outlets on each).
  - Four of the circuits (8 outlets) are powered off input A and four are powered off input B.
  - Since I only currently have 1 circuit in the basement, I have both PDU circuits connected to the two outlets on the one circuit. With my current equipment I'm well under the maximum usage.

I have a whole new set of network & server equipment on it's way, including a second PDU (identical to the one described above). I'd like to set up the power properly.

So a couple questions on the electrical wiring & components:

- Most of my home circuits are 20A on Romex 12-2. It appears that's common practice. However, since this PDU is specifically designed to run on 15A circuits, should I stick to setting up 15A circuits with 15A fuses in the box, or should I still install them as 20A circuits? As mentioned above, each PDU has an onboard 15A fuse for each input.
- If I install 15A fuses, I'm assuming I don't need to "downgrade" from Romex 12/2 to Romex 14/3. Sticking with the Romex 12/2 would allow the 15A breakers to be swapped out for 20A breakers in the future without rerunning the cable. Just looking to confirm there's nothing wrong with that.
- Is there any reason to install GFI outlets rather than just standard power outlets for this use-case? I would think not, since there's already a bunch of expensive electronics in the PDUs monitoring the circuits.

So based on that, I think I purchasing the following is everything I need to do complete the project:

- [Southwire Romex 12/2WG NMB](http://a.co/7YsF8j6) (250ft)
- [12/2 Plastic Staples](http://a.co/hWASJPO)
- [GE 15A Single Pole Thin Breaker](http://a.co/ikhCLce) (4x)
- [4 Gang New Work Box](http://a.co/7UUpX8Y)
- [4 Gang Wall Plate](http://a.co/dsZAKTB)
- [15A Receptacle](http://a.co/hemUfvp) (4x)

Does this look good?

I understand that the first impulse is to tell me to have a licensed electrician perform the work. I understand that, respect that, and in the end it may be what I do. I'm got several books on home wiring I'm currently reading and I would like to to do this myself, however if I don't feel comfortable doing it, I'll just have my electrician come out.

So all that being said - any advice or suggestions?

Comment: Please simplify (vastly) to ask one specific question per post. An in-depth discussion of all facets of your project isn't nearly as valuable to the community as smaller questions.

Comment: Also, avoid using brand names where possible as 1) they're copyrighted, and 2) they sometimes don't translate well in our global community.

Comment: @isherwood -- there is nothing wrong with using a trademark to refer to the product/brand the trademark refers to (i.e. nominative use) -- you do have a good point re: brand names not translating well though